# Login button event not fully working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

```
public partial class login_ : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    handler h1 = new handler();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = urname01.ID;
        string pass = pwd01.ID;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = h1.get_us().userLogin(email, pass);
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string id_= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_id_"].ToString();
            Session["admin_id"] = id_;
            string email_ = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_login_email_"].ToString();
            Session["admin_email"] = email_;
            string password_ = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_password_"].ToString();
            Session["admin_password"] = password_;
            string rights_= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_rights_"].ToString();
            Session["rights"] = rights_;
            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("start_home_.aspx");
        }
    }       
}    
}
```

this is second page!

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string primary = "1";
        //string supper = "0";
        if (Session["admin_email"] != null && Session["admin_password"] != null)
        {
            //if ( Session["rights"].ToString() == "0" || Session["rights"].ToString() =="1")
            //{

            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    Response.Redirect("login_.aspx");
            //}
        }
        else
            {
                Response.Redirect("login_.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

login button event redirect my page after checking user's username and password
but not make session which show null session on next page and when i am trying to debug login button,it redirect to next page without break at breakpoints
Thanks in advance[image: this is my login page]


`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login_.aspx.cs%>" Inherits="SiBKPK.login_" %>`

Comment: Can you post your code, on mobile phone it's difficult to read text in picture

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? You say breakpoints aren't hit, have you built it in debug or release? Release does not include debug symbols.

Comment: will you please show your second page code..

Comment: Did you configure your session correctly in the web.config? See the link below https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: feeeper  not i did change in config file because session have some defualt setting

Comment: JeremyThompson code uploaded

Comment: you are getting username and password from database, are you sure you are fetching them, there is no null in email_ & password_

Comment: AliUmair yes i am sure actually compiler not reading these line just redirect to next page

Comment: Please post your .aspx page's markup. I suppose you have changed your page name and your CodeBehind file name is still the older one..

Comment: Hey, what is the name of the second page (for which you have posted the code). Also, try to put a breakpoint on `Response.Redirect("start_home_.aspx");` line. It could also be that username and/or password are incorrect so ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count is ZERO.

Comment: ManishDalal upload